# Powershell script to remove old cached Credentials (Error1168)

Tags: powershell, credentials

I'm pretty new to powershell and tried to write a script that deletes the old Credentials after the AD password changed, using this [PowerShell Credential Manager module](https://github.com/davotronic5000/PowerShell_Credential_Manager).

```
Import-Module N:\CredentialManager
$b = get-aduser -identity $env:username -properties passwordlastset
$x = Get-Storedcredential -AsCredentialObject 
foreach ($y in $x ){
    if($y.username -eq $env:username){
        #write-host "Username:"$y.username $y.LastWritten
        
            
           foreach ($a in $b){
                if($a.passwordlastset -lt $y.LastWritten){
                    foreach($y in get-storedcredential -AsCredentialObject) {
                    Remove-StoredCredential -type $y.type -Target $y.targetname
                }
                write-host "Credentials werden gelöscht"}

                    else{
                    write-host "Credentials werden nicht gelöscht"

                    }
              
                }
            }
        }
```

Im not sure what i have to pick for the type and target parameter here:
 `Remove-StoredCredential -Type  -target`
and everytime i try to run this script with diffrent parameters i get this error :
" Remove-StoredCredential : DeleteCred failed with the error code 1168. "

Comment: Where does `Remove-StoredCredentials` come from? It doesn't ship with Windows...

Comment: Its part of the Credentialmanager https://github.com/davotronic5000/PowerShell_Credential_Manager

Answer (score 1):

The objects returned by `Get-StoredCredential -AsCredentialObject` will have [`TargetName` and `Type` properties](https://github.com/davotronic5000/PowerShell_Credential_Manager/blob/master/PSCredentialManager.Object/Credential.cs#L11-L12) - pass these to `Remove-StoredCredential`:

```
foreach($cred in Get-StoredCredential -AsCredentialObject){
    Remove-StoredCredential -Type $cred.Type -Target $cred.TargetName
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast answer, i dont have the $cred variable defined, which one do i have to pick?  I'm sorry for those stupid questions, i'm in first year of computer science. The new Error code says that -Target needs a string and system.object can not be converted to system.string

Comment: @SNX In your example that would be `$y` in place of `$cred` (you're using `$y` to iterate over `$x` in your loop, the same way I'm using `$cred` to iterate over the output from `Get-StoredCredential ...` in my example)

Comment: i did this but i still recieve the error that a system.object cant get converted to a system.string. $y.targetname seems to be wrong

Comment: @SNX Can you please add the new error message (the whole thing, as-is) to your question as well?